# Is the time ordering in Dyson series either 1 or -1?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Because I think to make it a unitary operator, the norm of the unitary operator should be one. But I did not see any claim about the value of time ordering in Dyson series.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not too clear. Can you define what exactly you mean by "value of time ordering"?

Answer (score 1):

The unitary operator $U$ is not a real number, so $|U|=1$, whatever $|U|$ exactly means, does *not* imply $U\in \{+1,-1\}$ in any way. The unitary operator isn't even a complex number. It's more complicated than that.

Moreover, time ordering isn't a "unitary operator". It isn't even an operator in the same sense as unitary operators in quantum mechanics. It is a "meta-operator", just a symbol to order the factors that follow it. So unlike proper operators, it doesn't even have eigenvalues.

Comment: Perhaps OP is asking about the unitarity of $U\equiv\mathrm{Texp}[-iS]$, not of $\mathrm{T}$. Also, the $\pm 1$ may refer to the sign we get when time-ordering fermionic fields. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the value of T.

Comment: @diff - Accidental Fourier Transform wanted to make your question more clear but you returned to the previous short unclear version. Accidental Fourier Transform: you are introducing new possible confusions. There's no useful or usable way in which the action is an operator in quantum mechanics. What's the exponent in the time-ordered exponential is the integrated Hamiltonian over time which is something else than the integrated Lagrangian (action). Action appears in path integrals and the integrand is a c-number, not an operator. ... I am pretty sure OP didn't think about fermionic signs.